# Can not login on Joomla administration area

Tags: login, joomla1.0

I have troubles with my administrator login on Joomla 1.0.
Of course it's a old version but i want to try to upgrade but i can't login anymore.

I know my user is valid, because i made all the workarounds to reset the password or to insert a new user in table `jos_users`.

This what I've tried:

[Official Joomla Page - Reset Password](https://docs.joomla.org/Archived:Administration_FAQs_Version_1.0#How_do_I_recover_my_admin_password.3F)

[How to reset my Joomla administrator password?](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_reset_my_joomla_administrator_password/)

But nothing work.

When I login `www.myjoomla-instance.xyz/administrator/index.php`,
I receive a nearly blank page where is only written --> **`here`**

What does this mean ?
I've also seen there are 3 index-Files in the administrator-Folder:

`/httpdocs/administrator/index.php`

`/httpdocs/administrator/index2.php`

`/httpdocs/administrator/index3.php`

How can i solve my issue ?

Comment: Have you tried looking to see if there are anything in your server error logs? If you're getting the message `here`, then it's quite possible you site has been hacked, but then again, I'm not surprised to be honest :/ If I rightly remember, there are supposed to be 3 *index.php* files

Comment: Last J1.0 site I had access to, was back in 2009... Can't remember anything about it anymore... Things change way too fast...:-( But I agree with @Lodder, something is fishy there, smells on hacking...

Comment: It is better to start from scratch.

Comment: I am not sure anymore could we recommend action of overwriting all J!1.0 files with clear ones from installation archive?

Comment: Good idea. @blub, are you using exactly Joomla 1.0? Or perhaps an update, such as 1.0.15? Need the exact version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Joomla_Authentication was disabled in the database.
Using PhpMyAdmin simply go into the database, enabled authentication.

Answer (score 0):

3 steps are available to solve back end login problem:

1.Try to reset your joomla user name and password.
2.upgrading your joomla application.
3.c Panel -> php myadmin → choose the database →  find the record named authentication → joomla → press the pencil icon → you should see all preferences for this plugin, find the row called “published” and change its value from 0 to 1.
finally click the go button.